# How to kill just one Actor in Akka.net

Tags: c#, .net, akka.net

I have an Actor and a Instantiate then more then once. When a try to kill a specified ActorRef, all my actors is killed.

Example: This is my actor:

```
public class MyActor: ReceiveActor {
    public MyActor() {
         Receive<long>(id => Handler(id));
    }
    public void Handler(long id) {
        Console.WriteLine(id)
    }
}
```

And I can 'n' MyActor running, each binded with an `Id`.
But, when I try to kill a specified actor, it's killing all.

Example:

- I have MyActor running.
- Binded with ids: [1, 2, 3 , 4 ,5].
- And I have to kill the Actor with id 3.

So, I'm try to use this code in MyActor:

```
public void Handler(long id) {
    Console.WriteLine(id)
    if (id == 3)
        Self.Tell(Kill.Instance);
}
```

But, it's killing all MyActor.
What's wrong?

-- EDIT

```
public IActorRef ScheduleTellRepeatedly<T>(TimeSpan initialDelay, TimeSpan interval, object message) { 
    var actorRef = ActorSystem.ActorOf(ActorSystem.DI().Props(typeof(T))); 
    ActorSystem.ScheduleTellRepeatedly(initialDelay, interval, actorRef, message, ActorRefs.NoSender)
    return actorRef;
}

var actor1 = ScheduleTellRepeatedly<MyActor>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 1);
var actor2 = ScheduleTellRepeatedly<MyActor>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 2);
var actor3 = ScheduleTellRepeatedly<MyActor>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 3);
var actor4 = ScheduleTellRepeatedly<MyActor>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 4);
var actor5 = ScheduleTellRepeatedly<MyActor>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 5);


actor3.Tell(Kill.Instance);
```

Comment: Please show me how you instantiate the actor.  It is possible that you are killing the 'parent' actor, and all other actors are siblings

Comment: @monstertjie_za Description eddited. Can you check?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code where you instantiate your actors, it is difficult to tell exactly what is happening.  But with your command handler set up the way it is, I'm guessing it is because you only have one actor spun up.  You can spin up multiple instances of the same actor as long as they all have a unique name/reference.  The following code will kill one of the actors, but keep the rest of them alive.

```
// Spin up five actors, each with a unique name/reference
// Fill in Props as needed
var actor1 = Context.ActorOf(MyActor.Props(), "MyActor_1");
var actor2 = Context.ActorOf(MyActor.Props(), "MyActor_2");
var actor3 = Context.ActorOf(MyActor.Props(), "MyActor_3");
var actor4 = Context.ActorOf(MyActor.Props(), "MyActor_4");
var actor5 = Context.ActorOf(MyActor.Props(), "MyActor_5");

// Kill the third actor by sending it a poison pill
actor3.Tell(PoisonPill.Instance);

// Send a message to any of the other actors
actor4.Tell((long)123); // Will write 123 to the console
```

NOTE: In the code above, the second (optional) parameter of the `ActorOf` method is simply a user-friendly name to give to the actors you create.  If you choose to not specify an actor's name, Akka will automatically generate a unique name for the actor.

## Update

Your latest code is set up correctly to kill just the actor you specify (`actor3`).  I copied/pasted your code, ran it, and verified the other four actors are still running.  I did notice your `MyActor` class is listening for a `long`, but you are passing it an `int`.  This may make it appear as though the other actors are shut down when they really aren't.

Comment: Hi, I changed the description, can you check?

Comment: @ThiagoMaia, you cannot return something from a `void` method.  Also, it is `Kill.Instance`, not `Kill.Instantiate`.  Fix your code and try running it to see if it works.

Comment: @ThiagoMaia, what happens when you run it now?

Comment: All actors is running, but when I kill the actor3. All my actors stoped

Comment: This is a just Demo Code, ok?